# How to set precedence when loading Java libraries when runing a class in VSCODE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In a Java project running in VSCODE, when executing a certain class, there is a conflict between the **rt.jar** library (from the JDK itself); and the referenced library **jaxb-api-osgi.jar**. Specifically, it loads the **javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext** class from the **rt.jar**; instead of the one included in **jaxb-api-osgi.jar**.

That is, I would like the referenced library **jaxb-api-osgi.jar** to have precedence over the **rt.jar**

This configuration in **settings.json** doesn`t helps:

```
{
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "c:\\PROYECTOS\\Librerias\\glassfish4\\jaxb-api-osgi.jar"
    ],
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Instalados\\Java\\jdk8u192-b12"
}
```

Comment: have you tried just switching the order of those two lines?

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `exclude` to exclude `rt.jar` library under `java.project.referencedLibraries` configuration.

  [*Example settings.json*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_manage-dependencies-for-unmanaged-folder)

  ```json
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": {
      "include": [
          "library/**/*.jar",
          "/home/username/lib/foo.jar"
      ],
      "exclude": [
          "library/sources/**"
      ]
  }
  ```
- Add the following configuration to `vmArgs` in [*launch.json*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch) to add the `jaxb-api-osgi.jar` library to the boot classpath of the JVM with a higher priority than the default boot classpath (which includes `rt.jar`)

  ```json
  // Modify the path to your actual jaxb-api-osgi.jar path
  "-Xbootclasspath/p:${workspaceFolder}/lib/jaxb-api-osgi.jar"
  ```

  *Note: The launch.json file will only be referenced by using `Starting Debugging` or `Run Without Debugging` or executing the file in the **Run and Debugging** panel.*

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The contribution is very interesting. I have learned a lot from it.

But, it hasn't worked for me.

However, I put the details of the changes here because I'm sure it will help someone.

I finally got everything working for me from a clean workspace using **Maven projects**.

(I give the answer as good because of the detail of it, and because surely I was missing something to do correctly).

**settings.json**:

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": {
        "include": [
            "lib/**/*.jar",
            "C:\\PROYECTOS\\Librerias\\glassfish4\\jaxb-api-osgi.jar",
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "C:\\Instalados\\Java\\jdk8u192-b12\\jre\\lib\rt.jar"
        ]
    }
}
```

**launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Main",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "tirea.sfe.facturae.Main",
            "projectName": "SFEAAPP_bcc312b8",
            "vmArgs": "-Xbootclasspath/p:${workspaceFolder}/facturae/lib/jaxb-api-osgi.jar"
        }
    ]
}
```